# Place triangle arrows around first elements in CSS menu

Tags: css

i was checking out [this excellent demo](http://www.red-team-design.com/css3-animated-dropdown-menu#comment-78566) of drop down menus created with CSS, and i was curious, **how does the author place those triangle arrows around the first `li` element of each menu?**

i'm assuming it's done w/ some `:before` or `:after` pseudo-element magic, and when i comment out the following lines of the CSS, they disappear:

```
#menu ul li:first-child > a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: -6px;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #444;
}
```

but how does the author get them to be triangle shaped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last 3 lines do the trick:

```
border-left: 6px solid transparent;
border-right: 6px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 6px solid #444;
```

mind that both width and height are 0, so all you see are the borders. More examples [here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/).

Answer (score 4):

They are created using borders. Where borders meet they intersect at 45 degrees. So by making an element 0x0 pixels with large borders of different colours, you can make triangles. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work/7073558#7073558) for a fuller explanation.